# Neo4j-spatial importing OSM mismatching vertices gets stuck?

Tags: java, neo4j, openstreetmap, neo4j-spatial

Related to this question ([Neo4j-spatial importing OSM missmatching vertices found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819984/neo4j-spatial-importing-osm-missmatching-vertices-found)). This process of finding mismatches gets stuck.

```
new-york-latest.osm[147787947]: Re-indexing with GraphDatabaseService: 

community single [path../osm-db] (class: class org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade)
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[21793401]: 1 != 59
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[21038344]: 1 != 2
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[21740097]: 1 != 4
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[25024771]: 1 != 4
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[22277446]: 1 != 10
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[24715454]: 1 != 2
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[24649260]: 1 != 3
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[24464476]: 1 != 4
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[24400719]: 1 != 3
Mismatching vertices size for LineString:Node[24241961]: 1 != 3
```

And then it was stuck...

```
11169  java         0.7   02:03.51 62    1    161   56M    0B     294M   11148 1     stuck    *0[2]           0.00000
```

Is there any explanation for this? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a random fatal error, I retried using the provided "map.osm" file and this works fine. I do not want to know what is going to happen when trying to import the entire us-northeast though.